# How can I call multiple methods on an object if there are blocks involved?

Tags: ruby

Assume the string argument might include integers:

```
def turn_string_into_integer_array(string)
    array = string.split(" ").collect { |i| i.to_i }
end
```

If in the same line I wanted to use the inject method to sum the integers how would I do that given that I have a block at the end of the statement?

Comment: `string.split(" ").collect(&:to_i).inject(:+)`.. Is this what you want?

Comment: Do I have to use this notation or can you continue after do/end or {} notation as well?

Comment: same as `string.split(" ").collect { |i| i.to_i }.inject(:+)`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Don't answer in comments. That's what answers below question are for.

Comment: @MBO  Correct!! I don't know a ghost error was coming in my case.. Thus I answered here.. I couldn't submit for that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just chain it on the end of the block with a period

```
def turn_string_into_integer_array(string)
  string.split(" ").collect { |i| i.to_i }.inject(:+)
end
```

Comment: I did in the comment.. :p

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call the method?

```
string.split(" ").collect { |i| i.to_i }.inject(0) {|acc, el| acc + el }
```

However, this would be more idiomatically written as

```
string.split(" ").map(&:to_i).inject(0, :+)
```